# How to work with over-sized views and iOS storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a view controller with a simple layout. A single scrollview takes up the entire view. The scrollview will have a view inside that is twice it's size in height. The view inside will be static and it will be considerably easier and less time consuming to layout all the assets from the storyboard. The issue I am having is laying out all the assets that would initially be off screen.

Before, when using a nib file, I was able to add a the over-sized view outside of the main view. Lay everything out, then add the view into the main view from the code. With the new storyboards I can't seem to figure out a comparable solution to working with views larger than the device screen.

Is there any solution to working with large views?

Comment: Answered by Alex Reynolda @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-scrollview-in-storyboard/12905569#12905569

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll large views around with a two-finger drag within the screen-sized containing frame of the "scene" - I have only done this with static table views but I assume the principle is the same for scroll views since table views inherit from them.

It's not the best. There should be a way of dropping a view outside a scene and connecting to it, but there isn't.