# How to use UIScrollView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I have a scroll view with content that is 1000px tall and would like to be able to lay it out for easy design on the storyboard.
I know it can be done programmatically but I really want to be able to see it visually. Every time I put a scroll view on a view controller it won't scroll. Is it possible to get it to work like I want or do I have to do it in the code?

Comment: Hi everyone please see comments below for new ways to do this. I wrote this 2 years ago and xCode has changed a lot. There are other ways to do this now so be aware. iOS 7 and iOS 8 solutions suggested in the comments

Comment: Here is am again 2 years later still getting comments about how this doesn't work or autolayout is better. The original question was how to do it in ios 5/6. I only use autolayout these days for this so you should/can too. See the answers on autolayout for help. Please Upvote the autolayout answers if they are helpful. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I just spent 2 hours to find the solution and StackOverflow allows this QA style.

Start to finish here is how to make it work in storyboard.

1: go to you view controller and click on `Attribute Inspector`.

2: change Size to `Freeform` instead of Inferred.

3: Go to the main view on that storyboard, not your scrollview but rather the top level view.

4: Click `Size Inspector` and set this view to your desired size. I changed my height to 1000.

Now you will see that you storyboard has your view setup so you can see the entire height of your scroll for easy design.

5: Drop on a scrollview and stretch it so it takes up the whole view. You should now have a scrollview with size of 320,1000 sitting on a view in your view controller.

Now we need to make it scroll and need to make it show content correctly.

6: Click on your scrollview and click on `Identity Inspector`.

7: Add a `User Defined runtime attribute` with KeyPath of `contentSize` then type of SIZE and put in your content size. For me it is (320, 1000).

Since we want to see our whole scroll view on the storyboard we stretched it and it has a frame of 320,1000 but in order for this to work in our app we need to change the frame down to what the visible scrollview will be.

8: Add a `runtime attribute` with KeyPath `frame` with Type RECT and 0,0,320,416.

Now when we run our app we will have a visible scrollview has a frame of 0,0,320, 416 and can scroll down to 1000. We are able to layout our subviews and images and whatnot in Storyboard just the way we want them to appear. Then our runtime attributes make sure to display it properly. All of this without 1 line of code.

Comment: If you correctly use the scrollview autosizing feature, then you don't need to define the `frame` attribute. Indeed, all devices does not have the exact same size (iPhone 5).

Comment: Tronix117, then how do you solve this problem without that attribute?

Comment: If you have a solution for iOS 7 let me know. This answer was posted over a year ago before iOS 7. I'm swamped or else I'd update this for iPhone5 and ios7

Comment: i can confirm ChuckKelly, that it is not working on iOS7

Comment: **NOTE: Solution for FOR iOS7 is down below** http://stackoverflow.com/a/22489795/1553014

Comment: If you want to retain auto-layout, then follow zloidooraque's answer.  Kyle Clegg's answer regarding maintaining different screen sizes is spot on, considering the addition of the iPhone 6 family's device sizes.

Comment: I prefer to set the size of scrollView fitting with __viewport__ for constraining visible area, equal to the size of "one slider".

Comment: Note:  For iOS 8.3 XCode 6.3, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742230/uiscrollview-in-storyboard-not-working-with-ios-8-size-classes-and-autolayout

Comment: @Tronix117 How to have a content view that would automatically determine which screen size to scroll or not?

Comment: These days, I would use any of the following three alternatives instead of this accepted answer: [top-to-bottom-constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35372128/199364) , or [stack view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38930223/199364), or [constrain to position of bottom item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491457/199364). My point is that with correct constraints, you should be able to do whatever you want visually in storyboard, *without* hardcoding the final height into contentSize. Perhaps do still use FreeForm if that makes it easier to lay out.

Comment: What about changing contentSize dynamically because all iPhones comes with a different sizes

Comment: Yea, the height is grayed out for me in the size inspector.

Answer (score 53):

Here are the steps with **`Auto Layout`** that worked for me on XCode 8.2.1.

1. Select `Size Inspector` of `View Controller`, and change `Simulated Size` to `Freeform` with height **1000** instead of `Fixed`.
2. Rename the view of `View Controller` as **RootView**.
3. Drag a `Scroll View` as subview of **RootView** and rename it as **ScrollView**.
4. Add constraints for **ScrollView**:

   - **ScrollView**[Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing] = **RootView**[Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing]
5. Drag a `Vertical Stack View` as subview of **ScrollView** and rename it as **ContentView**.
6. Add constraints for **ContentView**:

   - **ContentView**.height = **1000**
   - **ContentView**[Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing, Width] = **ScrollView**[Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing, Width]
7. Select `Attributes Inspector` of **ContentView**, and change `Distribution` to `Fill Equally` instead of `Fill`.
8. Drag a `View` as subview of **ContentView** and rename it as **RedView**.
9. Set `Red` as the background of **RedView**.
10. Drag a `View` as subview of **ContentView** and rename it as **BlueView**.
11. Set `Blue` as the background of **BlueView**.
12. Select **RootView**, and click `Update Frames` button.

    - `Update Frames` is a new button in Xcode8, instead of `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` button. It looks like a refresh button, located in the control bar below the Storyboard:
      [image: Update Frames Button]

---

View hierarchy:

- **RootView**

  - **ScrollView**

    - **ContentView**

      - **RedView**
      - **BlueView**

---

View Controller Scene (Height: 1000):

[image: scene]

Run on iPhone7 (Height: 1334 / 2):

[image: demo]

Comment: i am having the same issue and wondering if this would work when my scrollview is not the size of rootview?

Comment: But the thing is that it wil have a blank space at the  bottom for ipad

Comment: A note for setting `BlueView`'s top to `RedView`'s bottom for beginners like me (Xcode 8.2): 1) Drag the `BlueView` *below* `RedView` (i.e. they should not overlap or step 4) will not work). 2) Open the pin menu at the bottom. 3) Click the small arrow to the right of the top margin constraint. 4) Select `RedView` from that menu and set the value to 0. This is different from previous Xcode versions where you could do things like `Editor` --> `Pin` --> ...

Comment: just curious, why do you use a vertical stack view instead of a regular UIView?

Comment: @Changerrs I use `UIStackView` to avoid the trouble of setting constraints.

Comment: +1 for the freeform. I never thought I'd get away with that as a way of layout out the scrollview programmatically.

Comment: What about changing contentSize dynamically because all iPhones comes with a different sizes

Answer (score 44):

**Here are the steps that worked for me on iOS 7 and XCode 5.**

1. Drag a ViewController (it comes with UIView "View").

   1.1 Select "View Controller" and select "File Inspector" and uncheck "Auto layout".
2. Drag a ScrollView (as child of ViewController's UIView "View")
3. Select ScrollView and open "Identity Inspector".
4. Enter "contentSize" for keyPath. Select "Size" for  Type. And Enter **{320, 1000}** for value.

   Note: Step 4 is simply saying that the scroller contains some content whose size is 320x1000 units. So setting contentSize will make scroller work.
5. Select View Controller, Select "Attributes Inspector" then select **Freeform** from Size.

   Note: step 5 will allow us to change the size of "View" that the view controller comes with.
6. Select "View" and then select "Size Inspector".
7. Set Width to 320 and height to 1000.

Note: 5, 6 & 7 is purely for us to *see* stretched or entire expanded view inside StoryBoard.
Note: Make sure to unselect "Auto Layout" on View Controller.

**Your View hierarchy should look like:**
[image: hierarchy]

Comment: This technique still works as of Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1.

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks for this.  Definitely works on Xcode 6.1 & iOS 8.1 as mentioned.

Comment: Ok...so what about if we NEED autolayout?

Comment: Solution for `Auto Layout` is **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32600396/1260976)**.

Comment: Solution for iOS 8 Auto layout and size class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742230/uiscrollview-in-storyboard-not-working-with-ios-8-size-classes-and-autolayout

Comment: Any of the following alternatives solve this, using autolayout, *without* hardcoding the total size: [top-to-bottom-constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35372128/199364) , or [use stack view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38930223/199364), or [constrain to position of bottom item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491457/199364).

Comment: What about changing contentSize dynamically because all iPhones comes with a different sizes

Answer (score 14):

After hours of trial and error, I've found a very easy way to put contents into scrollviews that are 'offscreen'. Tested with XCode 5 & iOS 7. You can do this almost entirely in Storyboard, using 2 small tricks/workarounds :

1. Drag a viewcontroller onto your storyboard.
2. Drag a scrollView on this viewController, for the demo you can leave its size default,
   covering the entire screen.
3. Now comes **trick 1** : before adding any element to the scrollView, drag in a regular 'view' (This view will be made larger than the screen, and will contain all the sub elements like buttons, labels, ...let's call it the '**enclosing view**').
4. Let this **enclosing view's Y size** in the size inspector to for example 800.
5. Drop in a label onto the enclosing view, somewhere at Y position 200, name it 'label 1'.
6. **Trick 2** : make sure the **enclosing view** is selected (**not the scrollView !**), and set its Y position to for example -250, so you can add an item that is 'outside' the screen
7. Drop in a label, somewhere at the bottom of the screen, name it 'label 2'. This label is actually 'off screen'.
8. Reset the Y position of the enclosing view to 0, you'll no longer see label 2, as it was positioned off screen.

So far for the storyboard work, now you need to add a single line of code to the viewController's 'viewDidLoad' method to set the scrollViews contents so it contains the entire 'enclosing view'. I didn't find a way to do this in Storyboard:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
}
```

You can try doing this by adding a `contentSize` keyPath as a `size` to the scrollView in the Identity Inspector and setting it to (320, 1000).

I think Apple should make this easier in storyboard, in a TableViewController you can just scroll offscreen in Storyboard (just add 20 cells, and you'll see you can simply scroll), this should be possible with a ScrollViewController too.

Comment: that is correct jaxvy, when I recentlyported my app to support auto layout, I have replaced the scrollview with a static table view. Does the same job, and has some extra advantages too.

Comment: What about changing contentSize dynamically because all iPhones comes with a different sizes

Answer (score 9):

**Getting Scrolling to work in iOS7 and Auto-layout in iOS 7 and XCode 5.**

In addition to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489795/1553014

Apparently, all we need to do is:

1. Set all constraints to Scroll View (i.e. fix scroll view first)
2. Then set distance-from-scrollView constraint to the bottom most item to scroll view (which is the super view).

Note: Step 2 will tell storyboard where the last piece of content lies within Scroll view.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to setup a scrollview using Xcode 11

1 - Add scrollview and set top,bottom,leading and trailing constraints

[image]

2 - Add a Content View to the scrollview, drag a connection to the Content Layout Guide and select Leading, Top, Bottom and Trailing. Make sure to set its' values to 0 or the constants you want.

[image]

3 - Drag from the Content View to the Frame Layout Guide and select Equal Widths

[image]

4 - Set a height constraint constant to the Content View

Comment: Awesome. Critical one's solution in 4 steps.

Answer (score 8):

For this example, I have unchecked the Autolayout feature of the Interface builder. And, I'm still using (for no reason at all) the relatively old 4.6.1 version of Xcode.

Start with a view controller that has a scroll view over it (the main view).

1: Add a Container View, from the Object Library, to the scroll view. Notice that a new view controller is added to the storyboard and it is linked to the view controller with the scroll view.

2: Select the container view and, on the Size Inspector, make it anchor to top and left without auto resizing.

[image]

3: Change its height to 1000. (1000 is used for this example. You should apply the value that you require.)

4: Select the new view controller and, from the Attributes Inspector, change Size to Freeform.

[image]

5: Select the view of the new view controller and, on the size Inspector, change the height to 1000 (which is equal to the container view's height).

6: For your test later, while still on the view of the new view controller, add a label at the top and at the bottom of the view.

7: Select the scroll view from the original view controller. On the Identity inspector, add an attribute with the keyPath set to contentSize, type set to Size, and value set to {320, 1000} (or your container view's size).

[image]

8: Run on the 4-inch iPhone Simulator. You should be able to scroll from the top label up to the bottom label.

9: Run on the 3.5-inch iPhone Simulator. You should be able to scroll from the top label up to the bottom label.

Remember that Xcode 4.6.1 can only build for iOS6 and below. Using this approach and building for iOS6, I am still able to achieve the same results when the app is run on iOS7.

Answer (score 5):

Note that within a `UITableView`, you can actually scroll the tableview by selecting a cell or an element in it and scrolling up or down with your trackpad.

For a `UIScrollView`, I like Alex's suggestion, but I would recommend *temporarily* changing the view controller to freeform, increasing the root view's height, building your UI (steps 1-5), and then changing it back to the standard inferred size when you are done so that you don't have to hard code content sizes in as runtime attributes. If you do that you are opening yourself up to a lot of maintenance issues trying to support both 3.5" and 4" devices, as well as the possibility of increased screen resolutions in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer :- Only for ios 9 and above (Stack View).

If you are deploying your app on ios 9 devices use a **stack view**.
Here are the steps :-

1. Add a scroll view with constraints - pin to left, right, bottom, top (without margins) to superview (view)
2. Add a stack view with same constraints to scroll view.
3. Stack View Other Constraints :- stackView.bottom = view.bottom and stackView.width = scrollView.width
4. Start adding your views. The scroll view will decide to scroll based on the size of the stack view (which is essentially your content view)

Comment: This is a useful technique, that minimizes the number of constraints you have to add manually. In general, the way to get scrolling is to ensure that there are sufficient constraints for autolayout to calculate the size of the content. Stack view does much of that constraining for you. Set stack's `spacing` to put some space between subviews (children). If need more space between just two subviews, add a "spacer" child: a transparent UIView with fixed size.

Answer (score 4):

You should only set the contentSize property on the viewDidAppear, like this sample:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(306,400.0);

}
```

It solve the autolayout problems, and works fine on iOS7.

Comment: NOTE: [Alex Zavatone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40004629/199364) gives an alternative way to set contentSize, without writing code.

Answer (score 4):

In  iOS7 I found that if I had a View inside a UIScrollView on a FreeForm-sized ViewController it would not scroll in the app, no matter what I did. I played around and found the following seemed to work, which uses no FreeForms:

1. Insert a UIScrollView inside the main View of a ViewController
2. Set the Autolayout constraints on the ScrollView as appropriate. For me I used 0 to Top
   Layout guide and 0 to Bottom layout Guide
3. Inside the ScrollView, place a Container View. Set its height to whatever you want (e.g. 1000)
4. Add a Height constraint (1000) to the Container so it doesn't resize. The bottom will be past the end of the form.
5. Add the line [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)]; to the ViewController that contains the scrollView (which you've hooked up as a IBOutlet)

The ViewController (automatically added) that is associated with the Container will have the desired height (1000) in Interface Builder and will also scroll properly in the original view controller. You can now use the container's ViewController to layout your controls.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because I like the technique; however I believe you are wrong about FreeForm VC interfering with scrolling, regardless of version of iOS. Starting with iOS 6 (which added Auto Layout), a complete set of constraints, as documented in other answers, *will* scroll. I don't think FreeForm interferes with that (though I haven't tried it). Perhaps you were missing some non-obvious constraint; ScrollView + AutoLayout is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 4):

i wanna put my 5 cents to accepted answer:
i've been researching topic for 2 days and finally found a solution that i will be using always from now on

go up to item 4 in accepted answer and forget about adding attributes of frames and contentsizes and so on

to make everything automatic just use solution from [this link](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/)

everything is clear, easy, elegant and works like a charm on ios 7. i'm pretty glad with all that lol

Comment: [updated link](https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/)

Comment: your solution (if you follow your link down to the end) involves adding a line of code, so this is not particularly in line with the question - using only storyboard

Comment: @BorisGafurov isn't it a bit outdated with ios7 anyway. and m.b. it isn't in line, but i'm sure it have helped couple of ppls anyway.. so let it be

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution.

1. Set the size attribute of your view controller in the storyboard to "Freeform" and set the size you want. Make sure it's big enough to fit the full content of your scroll view.
2. Add your scroll view and set the constraints as you normally would. i.e. if you wants the scroll view to be the size of your view, then attach your top, bottom, leading, trailing margins to the superview as you normally would.
3. Now just make sure there are constraints in the subviews of the scrollview that connect the top and bottom of the scroll view. Same for left and right if you have horizontal scrolling.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of a grubby answer that get's to the same solution for vertical scroll views, but (against the ethos of stackoverflow) doesn't answer the question. Instead of using a scrollView, just use a UITableView, drag a normal UIView into the header, and make it as big as you want, you can now scroll the content in storyboard.

Comment: IMHO, its a fine answer, not against stackoverflow's ethos, to suggest an alternative approach (unless OP specifically says they need to do it the way they are asking about.) And the biggest value of stackoverflow is helping all the *other* people who come along and read the Q&A. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you **don't need to specify height at all!**  Which is great if it changes for some reason (you resize components or change font sizes).

I just followed this tutorial and everything worked: http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

(Side note: There is no need to implement viewDidLayoutSubviews unless you want to center the view, so the list of steps is even shorter).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The key is the contentSize.

This is often missing and not indicated when adding a UIScrollView.

Select the UIScrollView and select the Identity Inspector.

Add a `contentSize` keyPath as a `size` to the scrollView in the Identity Inspector and setting it to (320, 1000).

Scroll away.

Comment: This is one approach, and I have used it myself. However, I don't consider it the preferred approach. It is "cleaner / more flexible" to provide a complete set of constraints, such that autolayout can calculate content size itself. Three alternatives: [top-to-bottom-constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35372128/199364) , or [use stack view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38930223/199364), or [constrain to position of bottom item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491457/199364).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto-layout than best approach is to use UITableViewController with static cells in storyboard.

I have also once faced the problem with a view that require much more scrolling so change the UIScrollView with above mentioned technique.