# UIScrollView does not work after adding elements to it

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I added a scrollview to my view and added the following code in my viewDidLoad-Method:

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
```

When i start the app with my empty scrollview i can scroll and also see the scrollbars, but when i add a label to the scrollview i can not scroll anymore and can´t see the scrollbars.

The problem is only when i add the label with the designer. Adding the label in the code works, like this example:

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
myLabel.text = @"My Label";
[scroller addSubview:myLabel];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @bluemagicon I've copy pasted your code and got everything works fine

Comment: As described the error happens onyl when NOT using the code but when the UI designer is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution here: [[How to use UIScrollView in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-scrollview-in-storyboard][1])

[1]: [How to use UIScrollView in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-scrollview-in-storyboard)