# Scrollable UIViewController in storyboard jumps always to the top

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have created a scrollable `UIViewController` with an `UIScrollView` with storyboard. On this screen are two `UITextView`, one `MKMapView`, two `UIDatePicker` and a `UIButton` at the bottom.

I designed it like it's descripted in [How to use UIScrollView in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-storyboard). In my code I added the following lines in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
    scrollView.addSubview(map)
    scrollView.addSubview(starttime)
    scrollView.addSubview(endtime)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 1000)
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 375,height: 667)
```

The screen is really scollable, but if I want to set a date with the two datepickers or I want to click the button at the bottom of the screen, the focus jumps always to the top of the screen. I always can handle the elements on the screen which are displayed on the start screen. Every element which is always reachable by scrolling is not usable. So, I can not use all elements on the `UIScrollView`. How is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried using contentInsets, and changing those when things are selected?