# UIScrollView Scrolling not Working, inside Buttons not working

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, xcode6

I created a UIScrollView from the Storyboard. I have "scrolling enabled" checked and I made sure all the Text boxes and buttons inside have user interaction enabled checked. However, the ScrollView doesn't scroll and the buttons and text fields can't be selected at all. Attached is a screenshot of the XCode Setup.[image]

Comment: You either net to make sure to set the scrollViews `contentSize` appropriately so that it will scroll or use `autolayout` to determine the `contentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view only scrolls if the content size of the scroll view is larger than the scroll view itself.
Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-storyboard) to see how a to correctly setup a scroll view in storyboard.

Comment: Should the buttons and text fields still work regardless?