# Define correctly height for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I'm creating a application using `Swift3`, and i have difficult to define correctly height for `UIScrollView`, i'm using `autolayout` and create this structure:

- `UIScrollView`

  - `UIView` // The container `view`
  - `UIImageView` // `Constraint` Top Edges  = 20 in relation to `UIView`
  - `UITextView` // `Constraint` Top Edges = 40 in relation to `UIImageView`
  - `UITextView` // `Constraint` Top Edges = 20 in relation to `UITextView`
  - `UIButton` // `Constraint` Top Edges 30 in relation to `UITextView`

Currently, i'm using this logic to calculate `UIScrollView` height

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var scrollHeight : CGFloat = 0.0

    for view in self.containerView.subviews {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        scrollHeight += view.frame.size.height
    }

    // Adding height for scrollview, according to the sum of all child views
    self.scrollView.contentSize.height = scrollHeight

}
```

But, i can only get the `views` height, and them not consider the `Constraints` "margins", i would like know any way to calculate correct height for `UIScrollView`, adjusted according their content.

Comment: If you add a constraint to the last button to the bottom of the scrollview you should  it have to set the size of the content manually.

Comment: @agibson007 but i don't add this constraint, only add constraint to the bottom of the uiview above

Comment: Yep that’s what I meant sorry.  That should work.  See this answer I gave a while ago.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684594/ios-uiscrollview-with-dynamic-content-using-containerview-step-by-step/42685952#42685952

Answer (score 0):

Close! Let's add the top margin for each view:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var scrollHeight : CGFloat = 0.0

    for view in self.containerView.subviews {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        scrollHeight += view.frame.size.height

        //Add the margins as well to the scrollHeight
        scrollHeight += view.layoutMargins.top
    }

    // Adding height for scrollview, according to the sum of all child views
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGRect(x: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, y: scrollHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.scrollview.contentsize.height = containerview.height;